# Laravel 7 submit button don't triggers route

Tags: php, laravel

I have contact form for sending e-mails. When i try submit my contact form, nothing happens. In dev-tools don't have any errors. And second problem - when i try to enter route in adressbar like myadress.lv/sendmail i have error -"The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."

Here is my blade

```
<form action="{{url('/sendmail')}}" method="post" id="contact">
    @csrf
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <fieldset>
                <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Jūsu vārds..." required="">
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <fieldset>
                <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" id="email" pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*"
                       placeholder="Jūsu e-pasts..." required="">
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <fieldset>
                <input name="subject" type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Temats..." required="">
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <fieldset>
                <textarea name="message" rows="6" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Jūsu ziņa..."
                          required=""></textarea>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <fieldset>
                <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="filled-button">Sūtīt ziņu</button>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is my route list

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('/kontakti', 'PagesController@contacts');
Route::post('/sendmail', 'MailController@sendMail')->name('send');
```

On other older Laravel versions this works fine, but in Laravel 7 it's not working.

Comment: if you name the route you can call it with this code `<form action="{{ route('send') }}"`

Comment: @GiacomoM Yes i know. But that still don't resolve this problem

Comment: No page reload or any other reaction in the browser when you hit submit?

Answer (score 0):

The second problem is because when you type an url into a browser you are doing a GET request. Your `'/sendmail'` route can only be accessed with a POST request.

For the first problem, your code should work so I guess the problem comes from somewhere else. You can debug with the dev tools by inspecting the form and see if it is the correct url there.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! 
I disconnected contacts blade from app layout and then submit button started triggering route so i founded that some of my html template scripts is blocking this operation . After i deleted

```
 <script src="scripts/vendors/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

everything works great.